# Call to a member function store() on null en carga de imagen Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, fileupload, laravel-livewire

Tengo la siguiente funcionalidad que estaba funcionando correctamente pero de repente me dejo de funcionar y no detecto cuál es el problema.

No tiene un form y tampoco uso el request. Por eso lo manejo de Livewire:

**Blade**

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label for="portada">Portada <small class="text-danger">*</small></label>
       <input wire:model="portada" type="file" class="form-control-file" name="portada" id="portada">
</div>
```

**Componente**

```
//Guardamos la foto de portada
    $pathFoto = $this->foto->store('imagenPortada');



    // Creamos primero el usuario
    User::create([
            'tipo_usuario' => $this->tipo_de_usuario,
            'name' => $this->nombre_usuario,
            'apellido' => $this->apellido_usuario,
            'documento' => $this->documento_usuario,
            'telefono' => $this->telefono_usuario,
            'telegram' => $this->telegram,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($this->password),
            'permiso' => $this->permiso,
            'perfil' => asset($pathFoto)
        ]);
```

El error:

> Call to a member function store() on null {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function store() on null

**Solución:**
Gracias @L.Flor, lo realice de la siguiente manera:

```
public $foto = null;


if(!empty($this->foto)){
        $pathFoto = $this->foto->store('imagenPortada');
    }else{
        $pathFoto = null;
    }
```

Comment: Podrías completamente el método en donde tengas esa línea `$path = $this->portada->store('imagenPortada');`?

Comment: Ahi subí el create que es todo lo que hace, cambié los nombres a $pathFoto = $this->foto->store('imagenPortada');

Comment: Lo que sucede es que la foto no es obligatoria y cuando viene null me da el error, pero antes funcionaba y ahora no eso me llama la atención.

Comment: En mi caso no trabaje con livewire pero debes estar pendiente de las propiedades o atributos del form e mi caso role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la foto no es un parámetro requerido, entonces sólo debes verificar que no sea null primero.

```
$pathFoto = '';

if(!empty($this->foto)){
    $pathFoto = $this->foto->store('imagenPortada');
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias !! en base a tu respuesta, tuve que hacer algunas modificaciones pero me sirvió para dar con la solución.

Comment: Me podrías decir que hiciste? yo tengo el mismo problema, pero yo si le coloco una imagen y me da error como que si no tuviera, ya que cuando quito el error y le doy guardar, me guarda. yo no manejo una ruta de guardado, sino que simplemente lo guarda en mi directorio public asi: $this->imagen->storeAs('imagenes',$this->nom_imagen,'publico'),  y me da el error: Call to a member function storeAs() on null en carga de imagen Laravel Livewire

Comment: Me parece que en tu caso estás pasando parámetros de más, 'imagenes' es el store y 'publico' ? probá primero de la siguiente manera:  $this->imagen->storeAs('imagenes'); y otra cosa que podes probar es usando store solamente. Después te fijas el nombre.